# why i get ssl misconfiguration error?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

i installed the Ssl certificate on my server but i have this error

> This server could not prove that it is spdns.ir; its security certificate is from vmi90749. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

[image: Ssl Certificate Err]

anyone can explain me what is the problem and how i should fix it  ?
tnx

Comment: is your certificate self signed?

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite self-descriptive. The certificate is issued to `vmi90749` name, while you are trying to access a `spdns.ir` name. There is nothing common between them. You need to install a certificate that is issued to `spdns.ir` name and make sure it is issued by a trusted authority. Preferrably from a globally trusted CA vendor (there are CAs that issue certificates for free).

As aside note: when requesting new certificate for `spdns.ir` name, make sure that the name is added to `Subject Alternative Names` certificate extension. Google Chrome deprecated `Subject` field.